# Prevent resending form without page.redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

maybe some of you know the problem, that a form gets resubmitted if pressing refreshing the browser by pressing F5.
I am looking for a way to prevent this, and all I have found is the solution to do a redirect on the same page after submit

```
Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
```

This DOES work, but my problem is, that I need to inject javascript into a placeholder after postback, and so this information is lost because of the Redirect.

```
PlaceHolder p1 = this.NamingContainer.Parent.FindControl("phPostScript") as PlaceHolder;
GenerateJsTag(script,p1);
Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
```

Is there a way I can prevent a resubmit without Redirect?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way I can prevent a resubmit without Redirect?

Even if there is , you should stick to that approach which is redirect after submit.

Regarding  JS after post back , I believe that you want to see those JS output even after refresh after redirect.

What you can do is to redirect to `Request.RawUrl+"#someValue"` and then in the pageLoad (not within `IsPostBack`) you can inject again those scripts , knowing that you already showed that to the user via that hashkey ( could be cookie also , or query string , doesn't really matter) - or to show a message like ("Message was already accepted"...) or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding following JavaScript code to your aspx page.

*Also, you should not be trying to disable F5 since there are many users out there who may need to use F5 during browsing with your website.*

```
//bind keydown event to method that disables F5
$(document).on("keydown", PreventRefresh);

function PreventRefresh(e) {
          var code = e.which || e.keyCode;
          if (code === 116) {
               e.preventDefault();
            }
}
```

Comment: Disabling basic browser functionality is not recommended imo

Comment: Yes, I agree with you 100%. That should be considered standard behavior and not changed.

Comment: I added a note to highlight what you said.